# contingence table with 3 variables

Tags: r

Hi i want to make a contingency table but with more than 2 variables
This is the example that i'm looking for :
variable example (die, age cat, glucose score)
Thank you so much for your future advice

```
           Age cat (n)  Glucose score
Die   |     18        | 2.24               |                  
No die|   20          | 3.31
```

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. What have you tried that didn't work? It's unclear what we're looking at and how this is a contingency table exactly

Comment: If you have a data frame with those columns and use `library(dplyr)`, something like `your_data %>% group_by(die) %>% summarize(across(c(glucose_score, age_cat), mean))`.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks this code works but i don't want the mean for people who die by each Age cat, i just want the number but for the glucose score i want mean. Do you know how can i do ? thank you

Comment: Finnaly i found it    your_data %>% group_by(age cat,die) %>% summarize(across(c(glucose, summary)) thank you so much

Comment: Glad you found it! Next time I'd suggest sharing a little bit of sample input as well as the desired output so we can understand better what you want to do and what you're working with.